# DAPR publish with metadata - where is the metadata?

Tags: c#, .net-core, publish-subscribe, dapr, cloudevents

I tried to publish a message with metadata using DAPR.

The producer is like this:

```
public class Message
{
    [JsonPropertyName("messageId")]
    public Int32 MessageId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("tenantId")]
    public Int32 TenantId { get; set; }

    public Message(int messageId, int tenantId)
    {
        MessageId = messageId;
        TenantId = tenantId;
    }
}

using var client = new DaprClientBuilder().Build();
var tenantId = Rnd.Next(0, _test.DifferentTenantIds)+1;
var metaData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "SessionId",$"TENANT.{tenantId}" }
};
var message = new Message(1, tenantId);
var status = client.PublishEventAsync("PRODUCT", "EVENT1", message, metaData, CancellationToken.None).Status;
```

The sending seems correct, the message arrives to the receiver side, but the sessionId is not there where I expect - the sessionId is empty, and debugging I can see the the `job` has only the commont attributes: id, source, type, datacontenttype, dataschema, subject and time:

```
using CloudNative.CloudEvents;
app.MapGet("/dapr/subscribe", ([FromServices] ILogger logger) =>
{
    var sub1 = new DaprSubscription("PRODUCT", "EVENT1", "productEvent1");
    logger.LogInformation("Dapr pub/sub is subscribed to {0}", JsonSerializer.Serialize(sub1));
    var result = Results.Json(new[] { sub1 });
    return result;
});

app.MapPost("/productEvent1", async ([FromBody] CloudEvent job, [FromServices] ILogger<ProductManagementApi> logger) =>
{
    var sessionId = job.GetAttribute("SessionId");
    logger.LogInformation($"* received a message A with sessionId={sessionId}");
    return Results.Ok();
}
```

The example uses basic DAPR configuration using Docker on local machine, REDIS as message queue provider.

Any advice?